# Why does my unity hang when importing an obj?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

This is the code for importing objs into my unity.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

public class ObjImporter : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject spawnPoint;
    public GameObject emptyPrefabWithMeshRenderer;
    public string meshPath;
    public GameObject spawnedPrefab;

    static float progressPercentageMin;
    static float progressPercentageMax;
    static float progressPercentage;

    public Texture2D barBG;
    public Texture2D barLoad;

    int noOfLines;

    void Start ()
    {
        progressPercentageMin = 0;
        progressPercentageMax = 0;
        progressPercentage = 0;
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        progressPercentage = Mathf.Lerp (progressPercentageMin, progressPercentageMax, Time.time * progressPercentageMax * 0.01f);
        if(Input.GetKeyDown("space")){
            Mesh importedMesh = GetComponent<ObjImporter>().ImportFile(meshPath);
            noOfLines = TotalLines(meshPath);
            spawnedPrefab=Instantiate(emptyPrefabWithMeshRenderer,spawnPoint.transform.position,spawnPoint.transform.rotation) as GameObject;
            spawnedPrefab.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh=importedMesh;
            spawnedPrefab.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = new Color(Random.value, Random.value, Random.value, 1.0f);
        }
    }

    public static void UpdateProgressBar()
    {
        progressPercentageMax += 10;
    }

    private struct meshStruct
    {
        public Vector3[] vertices;
        public Vector3[] normals;
        public Vector2[] uv;
        public Vector2[] uv1;
        public Vector2[] uv2;
        public int[] triangles;
        public int[] faceVerts;
        public int[] faceUVs;
        public Vector3[] faceData;
        public string name;
        public string fileName;
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    public Mesh ImportFile (string filePath){
        meshStruct newMesh = createMeshStruct(filePath);
        populateMeshStruct(ref newMesh);

        UpdateProgressBar();

        Vector3[] newVerts = new Vector3[newMesh.faceData.Length];
        Vector2[] newUVs = new Vector2[newMesh.faceData.Length];
        Vector3[] newNormals = new Vector3[newMesh.faceData.Length];
        int i = 0;
        /* The following foreach loops through the facedata and assigns the appropriate vertex, uv, or normal
         * for the appropriate Unity mesh array.
         */

        UpdateProgressBar();

        foreach (Vector3 v in newMesh.faceData)
        {
            newVerts[i] = newMesh.vertices[(int)v.x - 1];
            if (v.y >= 1)
                newUVs[i] = newMesh.uv[(int)v.y - 1];

            if (v.z >= 1)
                newNormals[i] = newMesh.normals[(int)v.z - 1];
            i++;
        }

        Mesh mesh = new Mesh();

        mesh.vertices = newVerts;
        mesh.uv = newUVs;
        mesh.normals = newNormals;
        mesh.triangles = newMesh.triangles;

        mesh.RecalculateBounds();
        mesh.Optimize ();

        UpdateProgressBar();

        return mesh;
    }

    private int TotalLines(string filePath)
    {
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (r.ReadLine() != null)
            {
                i++;
            }
            return i;
        }
    }

    private static meshStruct createMeshStruct(string filename)
    {
        int triangles = 0;
        int vertices = 0;
        int vt = 0;
        int vn = 0;
        int face = 0;
        meshStruct mesh = new meshStruct();
        mesh.fileName = filename;

        // Read and retrieve all the text in the file.
        StreamReader stream = File.OpenText(filename);
        string entireText = stream.ReadToEnd();
        stream.Close(); // End of stream.

        UpdateProgressBar();

        // Going through the retrieved text.
        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(entireText))
        {
            string currentText = reader.ReadLine();
            char[] splitIdentifier = { ' ' };
            string[] brokenString;

            UpdateProgressBar();

            while (currentText != null)
            {
                if (!currentText.StartsWith("f ") && !currentText.StartsWith("v ") && !currentText.StartsWith("vt ")
                    && !currentText.StartsWith("vn "))
                {
                    currentText = reader.ReadLine();
                    if (currentText != null)
                    {
                        currentText = currentText.Replace("  ", " ");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    currentText = currentText.Trim();                           // Trim the current line
                    brokenString = currentText.Split(splitIdentifier, 50);      // Split the line into an array, separating the original line by blank spaces
                    switch (brokenString[0])
                    {
                    case "v":
                        vertices++;
                        break;
                    case   "vt":
                        vt++;
                        break;
                    case "vn":
                        vn++;
                        break;
                    case "f":
                        face = face + brokenString.Length - 1;
                        triangles = triangles + 3 * (brokenString.Length - 2); /*brokenString.Length is 3 or greater since a face must have at least
                                                                                     3 vertices.  For each additional vertice, there is an additional
                                                                                     triangle in the mesh (hence this formula).*/
                        break;
                    }
                    currentText = reader.ReadLine();
                    if (currentText != null)
                    {
                        currentText = currentText.Replace("  ", " ");
                    }
                }
            }
            UpdateProgressBar();
        }
        mesh.triangles = new int[triangles];
        mesh.vertices = new Vector3[vertices];
        mesh.uv = new Vector2[vt];
        mesh.normals = new Vector3[vn];
        mesh.faceData = new Vector3[face];

        UpdateProgressBar();

        return mesh;
    }

    private static void populateMeshStruct(ref meshStruct mesh)
    {
        StreamReader stream = File.OpenText(mesh.fileName);
        string entireText = stream.ReadToEnd();
        stream.Close();

        UpdateProgressBar();

        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(entireText))
        {
            string currentText = reader.ReadLine();

            char[] splitIdentifier = { ' ' };
            char[] splitIdentifier2 = { '/' };
            string[] brokenString;
            string[] brokenBrokenString;
            int f = 0;
            int f2 = 0;
            int v = 0;
            int vn = 0;
            int vt = 0;
            int vt1 = 0;
            int vt2 = 0;

            UpdateProgressBar();

            while (currentText != null)
            {
                if (!currentText.StartsWith("f ") && !currentText.StartsWith("v ") && !currentText.StartsWith("vt ") &&
                    !currentText.StartsWith("vn ") && !currentText.StartsWith("g ") && !currentText.StartsWith("usemtl ") &&
                    !currentText.StartsWith("mtllib ") && !currentText.StartsWith("vt1 ") && !currentText.StartsWith("vt2 ") &&
                    !currentText.StartsWith("vc ") && !currentText.StartsWith("usemap "))
                {
                    currentText = reader.ReadLine();
                    if (currentText != null)
                    {
                        currentText = currentText.Replace("  ", " ");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    currentText = currentText.Trim();
                    brokenString = currentText.Split(splitIdentifier, 50);
                    switch (brokenString[0])
                    {
                    case "g":
                        break;
                    case "usemtl":
                        break;
                    case "usemap":
                        break;
                    case "mtllib":
                        break;
                        // 
                    case "v":
                        mesh.vertices[v] = new Vector3(System.Convert.ToSingle(brokenString[1]), System.Convert.ToSingle(brokenString[2]),
                                                       System.Convert.ToSingle(brokenString[3]));
                        v++;
                        break;
                    case "vt":
                        mesh.uv[vt] = new Vector2(System.Convert.ToSingle(brokenString[1]), System.Convert.ToSingle(brokenString[2]));
                        vt++;
                        break;
                    case "vt1":
                        mesh.uv[vt1] = new Vector2(System.Convert.ToSingle(brokenString[1]), System.Convert.ToSingle(brokenString[2]));
                        vt1++;
                        break;
                    case "vt2":
                        mesh.uv[vt2] = new Vector2(System.Convert.ToSingle(brokenString[1]), System.Convert.ToSingle(brokenString[2]));
                        vt2++;
                        break;
                    case "vn":
                        mesh.normals[vn] = new Vector3(System.Convert.ToSingle(brokenString[1]), System.Convert.ToSingle(brokenString[2]),
                                                       System.Convert.ToSingle(brokenString[3]));
                        vn++;
                        break;
                    case "vc":
                        break;
                    case "f":

                        int j = 1;
                        List<int> intArray = new List<int>();
                        while (j < brokenString.Length && ("" + brokenString[j]).Length > 0)
                        {
                            Vector3 temp = new Vector3();
                            brokenBrokenString = brokenString[j].Split(splitIdentifier2, 3);    //Separate the face into individual components (vert, uv, normal)
                            temp.x = System.Convert.ToInt32(brokenBrokenString[0]);
                            if (brokenBrokenString.Length > 1)                                  //Some .obj files skip UV and normal
                            {
                                if (brokenBrokenString[1] != "")                                    //Some .obj files skip the uv and not the normal
                                {
                                    temp.y = System.Convert.ToInt32(brokenBrokenString[1]);
                                }
                                temp.z = System.Convert.ToInt32(brokenBrokenString[2]);
                            }
                            j++;

                            mesh.faceData[f2] = temp;
                            intArray.Add(f2);
                            f2++;
                        }
                        j = 1;
                        while (j + 2 < brokenString.Length)     //Create triangles out of the face data.  There will generally be more than 1 triangle per face.
                        {
                            mesh.triangles[f] = intArray[0];
                            f++;
                            mesh.triangles[f] = intArray[j];
                            f++;
                            mesh.triangles[f] = intArray[j+1];
                            f++;

                            j++;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    currentText = reader.ReadLine();
                    if (currentText != null)
                    {
                        currentText = currentText.Replace("  ", " ");       //Some .obj files insert double spaces, this removes them.
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        UpdateProgressBar();
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        //GUI.Label (new Rect (20, 20, 100, 100), progressPercentage.ToString());
        GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(100, 100, 100, 20), barBG); 
        GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(100, 100, progressPercentage, 20), barLoad);
    }
}
```

A progress bar is supposed run smoothly when the model is loaded.
However, Unity hangs due to the loading of the modeland you can't actually see the progress of the bar.
Anyone knows how to delay the drawing of the progress bar so that it will be seen.

Answer (score 0):

The reasons Unity hangs is because Unity is (mostly) run on a single thread, Meaning the ImportFile function in Update will complete fully before the next line of code will be called which will prevent the OnGUI function from being called until the entire Update function is complete.

The only way around this is to use MultiThreading which can be tough in Unity since you can't access any of Unity's data outside of the main thread, so you will only have access to your own data in a separate thread.

https://web.archive.org/web/20140702033426/http://unitygems.com/threads/

Looks like the original website is down but this did a really good job of explaining threading in Unity for me and comes with some example code and use cases